# Flash drive can no longer be booted from

Tags: boot, usb

I used the universal usb installer to put Ubuntu on a flash drive, and my computer booted from it just fine, but I decided to try a few other versions of Linux before installing it.
So I reformatted the flash drive and then put Mint on it, but now the computer would not boot from the drive. After this I put Ubuntu back onto it and still the computer would not boot from the drive.

I'm almost entirely certain that I did everything the same when putting Ubuntu onto the drive that I did the first time.
I'm at a loss for what to do because I cant find any differences between now and when it was working.

This is a picture of what is displayed when I attempt to boot from the flash drive. As you can see it recognizes the flash drive, but does not boot.

Apparently I dont have enough "reputation" to post images, so here's a link https://i.stack.imgur.com/RINX2.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like you just formated the drive when you need to re-partition it.

Comment: @DnrDevil I've tried removing all the partitions on the drive and then creating a new primary partition and it didnt work.

Comment: what programs are you using to partition it/ make a boot image? Can you boot into any OS? what are your bios settings?

Comment: @DnrDevil I'm using the Command Prompt ran as the administrator to partition it, and I'm using the Pendrivelinux program to make the boot image. Right now there isnt any OS on the main hard drive in that computer, but I've tried an old Windows Vista install disk and that works. I have it set to boot from USB-ZIP first and then USB-FDD and then the Hard Disk.

Comment: Are you able to burn to a disk, If windows works from a disk Ubuntu should have no issues.

Comment: @DnrDevil Unfortunately I dont own a disk burner.

Comment: Only issue I can think it may be is that command prompt is not that great at partitioning drives, I would try to wipe the drive (zero format), partition it again then disable all boot options and do them one by one. Update your question with all the steps you have already done, what version you are installing, 32/64 bit, and what has happened/ happening.

Comment: make sure that you have boot partition working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out why it wasnt working, the program I was using was attempting to reformat the drive in fat32, but the drive is 64GB, so it's not supported by the file system. After I stopped the program from attempting to reformat it worked again.